# Eloquent collections: each vs foreach

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

Might not be a question specific to Eloquent collections, but it just hit me while working with them. Let's just assume we have a `$collection` object which is an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.

Now if we want to iterate over it, what are the pros and cons of using `each()` with a closure versus a regular `foreach`. Are there any?

```
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    // Some code
}
```

versus

```
$collection->each(function ($item) {
    // Some code
});
```

Comment: If you haven't already seen them, you may want to read the comments on the accepted answer. It is wrong, and I suggest you unaccept it.

Comment: as I'm trying that out just now in 5.1 each() method seems totally useless since it doesn't change $item anyhow.

Comment: Do you have a `return $item;` at the end?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

A `foreach` statement should be used as a sort of a way to cycle through a collection and perform some sort of logic on it. If what is in it effects other things in the program, then use this loop.

The `.each` method uses `array_map` to cycle through each of the objects in the collection and perform a closure on each one. It then returns the resulting array. That is the key! `.each` should be used if you want to change the collection in some way. Maybe it's an array of cars and you want to make the model upper case or lower case. You would just pass a closure to the `.each` method that takes the object and calls `strtoupper()` on the model of each Car object. It then returns the collection with the changes that have been made.

Morale of the story is this: use the `.each` method to change each item in the array in some way; use the `foreach` loop to use each object to affect some other part of the program (using some logic statement).

#### UPDATE (June 7, 2015)

As stated so Eloquently (see what I did there?) below, the above answer is slightly off.  The `.each` method using `array_map` never actually used the output from the `array_map` call.  So, the new array created by `array_map` would not be saved on the `Collection`.  To change it, you're better off using the `.map` method, which also exists on a `Collection` object.

Using a `foreach` statement to iterate over each of them makes a bit more sense because you won't be able to access variables outside the Closure unless you make sure to use a `use` statement, which seems awkward to me.

The implementation when the above answer was originally written can be [found here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L171-L182).

#### `.each` in Laravel 5.1

The new `.each` that they are talking about below no longer uses `array_map`.  It simply iterates through each item in the collection and calls the passed in `$callback`, passing it the item and its key in the array.  Functionally, it seems to work the same.  I believe using a `foreach` loop would make more sense when reading the code.  However, I see the benefits of using `.each` because it allows you to chain methods together if that tickles your fancy.  It also allows you to return false from the callback to leave the loop early if your business logic demands you to be able to.

For more info on the new implementation, check out [the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L99-L114).

Comment: This all made sense to me and then I used `.each` on a collection of arrays to cast each array as an object. I could dump the variable I was returning in the callback function, it was an object. but afterward.. still an array. I am worried I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: It sounds like you aren't returning the object. You need to make sure you are returning the casted object from the callback function so that it will be out into the array and not the I casted array.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and is based on a misunderstanding of the code.  The fact that .each uses array_map() is irrelevant, that's just an implementation detail. In fact the Laravel code for `.each()` doesn't even return the return value of `array_map()`, it's just ignored.  Both `.each()` and `foreach` are equally useful (or not useful!) for modifying the values.  See my answer for details.

Comment: In response to Damon's comment, `.map()` would allow you to do that.  The return value of the `.each()` closure is ignored and can not be used as a way to replace items in a collection (that's part of why searsaw's answer is incorrect).

Comment: This answer is horribly wrong. PHP objects are mutable, and whenever you pass them as variables you actually pass around references to them; hence you can *mutate an existing object* from within the body of a `foreach`, from within an `array_map` callback, or indeed from any code at all. That isn't a difference between `foreach` and `array_map`. You suggest that by returning something from the callback passed to `$collection->each()` you can modify the collection. That isn't true either. The `each` method used to call `array_map` (prior to April 2015), but it didn't use the return value.

Answer (score 21):

There is a lot of confusing misinformation in the existing answers.

### The Short Answer

The short answer is: **There is no major difference between using `.each()` vs. `foreach` to iterate over a Laravel collection.**  Both techniques achieve the same result.

### What about modifying items?

Whether or not you're modifying items is irrelevant to whether you use `.each()` vs. `foreach`.  They both do (and don't!) allow you to modify items in the collection depending on what type of items we're talking about.

- **Modifying items if the Collection contains objects**: If the Collection is a set of PHP objects (such as an Eloquent Collection), either `.each()` or `foreach` allow you to modify properties of the objects (such as `$item->name = 'foo'`).  That's simply because of how PHP objects always act like references.  If you're trying to replace the entire object with a different object (a less common scenario), use `.map()` instead.
- **Modifying items if the Collection contains non-objects**: This is less common, but if your Collection contains non-objects, such as strings, `.each()` doesn't give you a way to modify the values of the collection items.  (The return value of the closure is ignored.)  Use `.map()` instead.

### So... which one should I use?

In case you're wondering about performance, I did several tests with large collections of both Eloquent items and a collection of strings.  In both cases, using `foreach` was faster than `.each()`.  But we're talking about microseconds.  In most real-life scenarios the speed difference wouldn't be significant compared to the time it takes to access the database, etc.

It mostly comes down to your personal preference.  Using `.each()` is nice because you can chain several operations together (for example `.where(...).each(...)`).  I tend to use both in my own code just depending on what seems the cleanest for each situation.

Comment: what is no difference for you? a simple test resulted in ~1 second for 10000 iterations over a 1000 item with ->each and ~0.4 for the same collection. that is 2/5. if anything is objective it is these bare numbers - not the preference of chaining calls.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to what the two other answers say, `Collection::each()` does *not* change the values of the items in the Collection, technically speaking.  It does use `array_map()`, but it doesn't store the result of that call.

If you want to modify each item in a collection (such as to cast them to objects as Damon in a comment to the crrently accepted answer), then you should use `Collection::map()`.  This will create a new Collection based on the result of the underlying call to `array_map()`.

Comment: As of a few days after you wrote this answer, `Illuminate\Support\Collection::each()` [doesn't even use `array_map` any more](https://github.com/illuminate/support/commit/e75754d504e6c90371ffab17fe7b3c64ed8c3a23).

Answer (score 2):

It is more beneficial to use the latter: `each()`.

You can chain conditions and write clearer more expressive code, eg:

```
$example->each()->map()->filter();
```

This takes you closer to Declarative Programming where you tell the computer what to accomplish instead of how to accomplish.

Some useful articles:

https://martinfowler.com/articles/collection-pipeline/

https://adamwathan.me/refactoring-to-collections/

Comment: you said "chain conditions", but these are not conditions, these functions.

Answer (score 1):

`->each()` is the **same** as `foreach(...)` **but worse**.

The main difference here is [Variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).
In *classical* `foreach` you can easily operate variables declared before the `foreach`. If you are dealing with closure, you would need to [inheriting variables from the parent scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) with `use`. This feature is confusing, because when you use it, your function becomes scope dependant...

You can chain `->each()` with other functions, but since it does not change the values in the collection, it has very limited use case. And because it is "rare to use", it is not always easily recognizable by developers when they read your code.

Not many people will read your code, cherish those who will.

Answer (score -3):

The foreach() construct does not allow you to change the value of the array item being iterated over, unless you pass the array by reference.

```
foreach ($array as &$value) $value *= $value;
```

The each() eloquent method wraps the PHP array_map() function, which allows this.

Like the previous answer states, you should use foreach() if you have any other motivation. This is because the performance of foreach() is much better than array_map().

http://willem.stuursma.name/2010/11/22/a-detailed-look-into-array_map-and-foreach/

Comment: As with the other answer that mentions the same thing, the array_map() part is a misunderstanding of the Laravel code and the functionality of array_map().  The array_map() return value is ignored when you use `.each()`.  But you can use foreach as a reference as you mention, but you shouldn't do that if the Collection contains objects, such as Eloquent objects, because objects in PHP already act like references.