# Laravel Collection arrays to objects

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, collections

I am receiving an array of arrays, but would like each array to be an object.

I try this:

```
$objects->each(function($object) {
    return new Object($object);
});
```

but `$objects` is unchanged. I feel like based on the description of collection->each() and array_map, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592836/eloquent-collections-each-vs-foreach) that this should work. But it clearly it doesn't, and a coworker thought I was an alien for thinking it should work.. so I must be missing something.

Is there a really efficient way like this for iterating through a collection and converting arrays to objects? And.. if this isn't what ->each does.. what does it do?

Comment: What is the result of `dd($objects)` ? Please clarify what kind of collection is that and what the inner arrays contain.

Comment: pre `->each` it is `new Collection($arr)` where `$arr` is an array of object arrays.. ie `[['id'=>7,'name'=>'object7'], ['id'=>8,'name'=>'object8']]`. after the `->each` call it is unchanged