# Laravel - Method delete does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the error:

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method delete does
>   not exist.

**route:**

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

**my controller:**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user();
    $post= Post::where('id', $id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
    $post->delete();

    return view('/home', [
        'posts' => $post
    ]);
}
```

**view:**

```
  <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy', '$post->id') }}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
      {{ csrf_field() }}
       {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete" />
  </form>
```

I tried changing `method="post"` to `delete`: error is gone but nothing gets deleted..

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @agu laravel 5.4

Comment: Are you certain that `$post` is a model and not null or a collection?

Answer (score 30):

This is your code.

```
$user_id = Auth::user();
$post= Post::where('id', $id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
$post->delete();
```

just add `->each()` before delete like this,

```
$post->each->delete();
```

It work's for me.

Comment: @DoreenChemweno check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592836/eloquent-collections-each-vs-foreach

Answer (score 18):

Remove get() and it will work

```
$post= Post::where('id', $id)->where('user_id',$user_id);
$post->delete();

If you want to delete first document you can use : 

$post= Post::where('id', $id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->first();
    $post->delete();
```

However, you always need to check if $post is found as a query document or its null so addd :

```
if($post){
$post->delete();
}
```

Comment: but then he does not have the post, just a query builder.

Comment: If you want to delete first document, use first() instead of get().

Comment: Use dd($post) to debug. It its null means the document with the mentioned id and user_id was not found. Then you need to check you parameters. For now pass static parameters for id and user_id and check first. If it works means the delete function is working, Then you can check about parameters passed

Answer (score 3):

use **->first()** instead of **->get()**

you can't delete an entire collection with **delete()**

Answer (score 2):

Change `get` for `first`, and check if the post belongs to the user afterwards.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::where('id', $id)->first();
    if($post && $post->user_id == \Auth::user()->id){
         $post->delete();
         return view('/home');
    }else{
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get the error :: Call to a member function delete() on null

Comment: Just updated my code, you can validate the user after retrieving the post

Comment: The code looks right, make sure you are not retrying with a post that was already deleted on a previous test.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object is what i get now

Comment: Are you sure the post you are trying to delete actually exists on the database?

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->delete();
        //redirect to
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

view:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['posts.destroy', $post->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Try this.

hope you created the controller with

> --resource

flag.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $post = Post::where([
                    'id' => $id,
                    'user_id' => $userId

            ])->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'Post was successfully deleted!');
    return redirect()->route('posts.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As post id is primary key of `posts` table you can directly remove from table,
No need of `user_id`

To fetch user_id from Auth facade you should use,

```
$user_id = Auth::id();
```

Only by passing id should work,

```
Post::find($id)->delete()
```

However, if you know the primary key of the model, you may delete the model without retrieving it by calling the `destroy` method. In addition to a single primary key as its argument, the `destroy` method will accept multiple primary keys, an array of primary keys, or a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections) of primary keys:

```
Post::destroy($id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am able to delete one (or multiple) associated record(s) in a table:

```
RFIResponseFile::where('rfi_response_id',$response_id)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Post::where('id', $id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->delete();
```

Or

```
$post= Post::where('id', $id)->where('user_id',$user_id);
if($post->get()->count()){
    $post->delete();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In your controller

> Before change code

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user();
    $post= Post::where('id', $id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
    $post->delete();

    return view('/home', [
        'posts' => $post
    ]);
}
```

> After change code

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user();
        $post= Post::where(['id'=>$id,'user_id'=>$user_id])->get();
               Post::where(['id'=>$id,'user_id'=>$user_id])->delete();

        return view('/home', [
            'posts' => $post
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add this on top of view, i 've error like you and now solved, sorry for bad english.

```
 {!! Form::model($post, ['route' => ['posts.destroy', $post->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
```

and

```
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

on bottom

for controller

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->delete();

Session::flash('success', 'Menu was successfully deleted!');
return redirect()->route('posts.index');
```