# Laravel change every model in collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a collection of Items. Now, before I am sending it though my api, I want to change a value of the model (but I don't want to update my model in the database).

Now I want to loop though my collection and return it as json, but I am getting `invalid Payload`.

Here is the code I perform:

```
$trainees = Trainee::select();
        if(!$request->user()->hasPermission('read-trainees')) {
            $trainees->where('status', 1)->where('visible', 1);
        } else {
            $trainees->with(array('user'=>function($query){
                $query->select('id','firstname', 'lastname');
            }));
            $trainees->select('user_id');
        }
        $trainees->select('interested_jobs', 'graduation');
        $trainees = $trainees->get();
        return $trainees
            ->map(function ($item) {
                $item->id = encrypt($item->id);
                return $item;
            })
            ->toJson();
```

Comment: And the problem is only in the json conversion? The value is changed and the `$trainees` is the array you want?

Comment: Decrypting item id? It comes encrypted from the database?

Comment: I dont know if the collection is getting updated. Without the code everything works fine, but with this code it doenst work

Comment: That with decrypt was stupid from me. But now I get `call do undefined function toJson()`

Comment: @KuebelElch15 when you do `Trainee::each(...)` doens't  save the collection, just iterates over every item. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597163/7117697)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this in several ways.

Every [Eloquent collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections) extends the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#introduction) class, that let you use helpful methods like [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map) or [`each()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-each):

```php
// get your collection
$trainees = Trainee::all();

// customize them
$trainees->each(function ($trainee) {
  $trainee->id = encrypt($item->id);
});

return $trainees;
```

PS: By default, when returning an array/collection to an API Laravel will return it as JSON.

---

The second approach, more granular and recommended in my opinion, is to use [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#introduction). From the documentation:

> When building an API, you may need a transformation layer that sits
> between your Eloquent models and the JSON responses that are actually
> returned to your application's users. Laravel's resource classes allow
> you to expressively and easily transform your models and model
> collections into JSON.

So, you'll need to:

### 1. Generate your API Resource

```php
php artisan make:resource TraineeResource
```

### 2. Customize it

**App\Http\Resources\TraineeResource.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class TraineeResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => encrypt($this->id),
            // ...
        ];
    }
}
```

### 3. Apply it

In your controller:

**App/Http/Controllers/MyCoolController.php**

```php
use App\Http\Resources\TraineeResource;

public function aCoolMethod(Request $request)
{
    // get your collection
    $trainees = Trainee::all();

    // return it
    return TraineeResource::collection($trainees);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map) function to change the data for each item in a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections).

```
return $trainees
    ->map(function ($item) {
        $item->id = decrypt($item->id);
        return $item;
    })
    ->toJson();
```

Comment: This produces a `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::map()`

Comment: It seems the query is not yet executed. Add `->get()` before the `->map` function.

Comment: You need to assign the output of your `get()` function. `$trainees = $trainees->get();`

Comment: But the Id is not getting encrpyted. It is stilly an integer

Comment: @KuebelElch15 because you are decrypting instead of encrypting. Try do this instead: `encrypt($item->id);`

Comment: Yes I've found that out too. But that doesn't affect it. Look at my updated question. Thats my full logic