# Laravel array_forget() helper, for nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel, and I've a simple nested array

```
[
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name1', 'phone' => '0'],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name2', 'phone' => '00'],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'name3', 'phone' => '000']
]
```

I want to use Laravel array_forget() or any other simple way
to get this array without phones

Comment: Is it not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array ? Do you really need to use Laravel ?

Comment: Thanks @GabrielDevillers, but my question was about nested array, I tried to use Laravel helpers, it helps me to shorten my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$elements = [
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name1', 'phone' => '0'],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name2', 'phone' => '00'],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'name3', 'phone' => '000']
];

$elements_without_phones = collect($elements)->map(function ($element){
    array_forget($element, 'phone');

    return $element;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @HCK for helping me day by day, working good, but it's not working for relationship keys

Comment: @user9500574 for that case you could use [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#introduction). I've just post an answer in another question, give it a [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304346/laravel-change-every-model-in-collection/53304519#53304519). Read the second approach that I mentioned.

Comment: My array in fact was a converted from an eloquent collection, I tried your code but as I said, not working, for that, I converted it to an array, after that I converted it to array and using your code, not it's working great, CONFUSION :)

Comment: @user9500574 if your array came from an Eloquent collection, just avoid converting it to array and chain the `->map()` part in the eloquent collection: `$elements = Model::where('field', 'value')->get()->map(...);`

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at laravel's advanced collection methods - a handy bunch of helpers designed to work with array-like collections in Laravel. What you might need is namely the [`except()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-except)

Comment: I tried to use except() before converting my collection to array, but I failed also, for that I converted it to a simple array

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate the array of arrays, and apply the `array_forget()` function on every (sub)array.

```
$array = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name1', 'phone' => '0'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name2', 'phone' => '00'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'name3', 'phone' => '000']
];

foreach($array as &$sub_array) { //note the passing by reference
    array_forget($sub_array, 'phone');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
$collection = collect(['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100, 'discount' => false]);

$filtered = $collection->only(['product_id', 'name']);

$filtered->all();

// Output: ['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk']
```

Comment: laravel collection helper "only"

Comment: Please add some context, even a simple introduction such as "You can make use of Laravel Collection etc...". Also, the question is about nested arrays, so you're not fully answering the question here.

Comment: i.e $result = collect( $array )->map( function ($item) {
            return collect( $item)->only( [ 'id', 'name' ]);
        } )->toArray();

Comment: Actually missing a `toArray()` inside the closure but that actually replies to the question. Please edit your answer above accordingly.

Comment: You're right. The inner `toArray()` would be redundant.