# Laravel collection: Why is each not applied?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I am workign with a Laravel collection and given this code:

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

 $input = ['1234', 42, '12Beers'];
 $result = (new Collection($input))->each(static function($item) {
     return (int) $item;}
 )->toArray();
```

I'd expect the result to look like:

```
[
  0 => 1234
  1 => 42
  2 => 12
]
```

but I'm getting:

```
 [
  0 => "1234"
  1 => 42
  2 => "12Beers"
]
```

It's as if the each is not being applied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592836/eloquent-collections-each-vs-foreach

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use [`Collection::map`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map). [`each`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-each) is a foreach loop alternative in a sense that it doesn't change the state of the collection itself / it doesn't return a new collection with the result items.